# Is there a grep or shell script that uses a regex to change filenames?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

How can I recursively change `xxx-xxx_[a-zA-Z]+_\d+_(\d+)\.jpg` into `$1.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the various answers to this question on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/63421/bash-working-with-multiple-files-and-directories/63451#63451).  It is dealing with the same issue (renaming files using a regex).  [*And it took me ages to find it on StackOverflow - because it wasn't on SO but on SU!* :( ]

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

find . | while read OLD; do
    NEW="`sed -E 's/(.*\/)?xxx-xxx_[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_([0-9]+)\.jpg/\1\2.jpg/' <<< "$OLD"`"
    [ "$OLD" != "$NEW" ] && mv "$OLD" "$NEW"
done
```

Some notes on this:

- Piping the output of `find` to a `while read` loop is a neat way of reading the output of `find` one line at a time. It's nice because it'll process the files as `find` finds them without having to build up the whole list of files first, as would happen if you did `` `find` `` in backticks.
- If you have tons of unrelated files then you can add the `-regex` option to `find` as per soulmerge's answer, but if not eh, no need.
- I modified your regex to allow for directory names at the front. They'll get captured in `\1` and the number you're looking for will be `\2`.
- `sed <<< "$OLD"` is the same thing as `echo "$OLD" | sed`, just a little fancier...
- `[ "$OLD" != "$NEW" ] && mv` is the same thing as `if [ "$OLD" != "$NEW" ]; then mv; fi`, just a little fancier...

**Edit**: Changed `\d` to `[0-9]` for compatibility. I tested it on my Mac and it works. Here's what happened in a test directory I set up:

```
mv ./1/xxx-xxx_ERR_19_02.jpg ./1/02.jpg
mv ./2/xxx-xxx_BLAH_266_14.jpg ./2/14.jpg
mv ./xxx-xxx_ERR_19_01.jpg ./01.jpg
```

Comment: `find` is recursive, so it should!

Comment: use find's -name and -type f option to search for the file names instead.

Comment: Are you sure it works, I just got a the help info for something scrolling down the screen real fast?

Comment: It is tricky to handle file names with spaces or newlines using this technique (at best tricky; at worst, impossible).

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you the more verbose version that can handle *any* file name (even those that are in folders with white-space contaminated names):

```
# file rename.sh
old="$1"
new="$(dirname "$1")/$(echo "$(basename "$1")"|sed 's/^xxx-xxx_[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_//')"
mv "$old" "$new"

# execute this in the shell:
find . -regex "xxx-xxx_[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+\.jpg$" -exec ./rename.sh "{}" ";"
```

Comment: It matches a file name such as:
xxx-xxx_ERR_19_01.jpg

and returns 01

What do I do with that code?

Comment: and I don't think it does what I need:

I have

1/xxx-xxx_ERR_19_01.jpg
2/xxx-xxx_ERR_19_01.jpg
3/xxx-xxx_ERR_19_01.jpg

Comment: ... fixed, need a helper file, but can handle anything now.

Comment: Hm.. didn't work :(
The command just finished quickly. Maybe find needs an argument to be recursive?

Comment: `find` is recursive by default. You have to specify options if you want it to **not** be.

Comment: The '[0-9]+' is not a portable 'sed' regular expression.  Also, you have to write the 'rename.sh' command each time you need to do one of these renaming exercises (it is customized to one replacement pattern).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `rename` (or `prename`) command (it's a Perl script that sometimes comes with Perl):

```
find -type d -name dir -exec rename 's/xxx-xxx_[a-zA-Z]+_\d+_(\d+)\.jpg/$1.jpg/' {}/xxx-xxx_[a-zA-Z]*[0-9].jpg \;
```

Comment: What is the  rename 's/ for? I don't understand what the 's' is for?

Comment: `s/.../.../` is Perl's (and `sed`) substitute command. It searches for the regular expression between the the first and second slashes and replaces it with what's between the second and third slashes. The `$1` is a back reference to the part of the regular expression that's in parentheses (`sed` uses `\1`).

Comment: The answer is flawed on two counts: (1) the replacement string should be '$1.jpg' instead of '$1', and (2) the rename or prename script is not distributed as standard with Perl (not on all platforms, at any rate).  Nevertheless, the 'rename' Perl script is a valuable tool - see http://superuser.com/questions/63421/

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path -type f -name "???-???_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*_*.???" | while read FILE
do
  f=${FILE%%.???}  
  number=${f##*_}
  extension=${FILE##*.}
  path=${FILE%/*}
  echo "mv '$FILE' '$path/$number.$extension"
done
```